# Is it safe to share OracleConnection to execute many OracleCommands concurrently?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, concurrency, oracle-manageddataaccess

I'm trying to avoid to open and close the connection for each command with the intention of improve performance, the list of commands is really huge.
Testing mannually this approach appears to work well, but I couldn't find at Oracle Docs any mention if it is valid or thread unsafe.
Could anyone confirm if is it Ok ?

```
OracleCommand[] commands = CreateOracleCommands();

using var conn = CreateOracleConnection();

Parallel.ForEach(commands, options, async cmd =>
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
});
```

I'm using asp.net core MVC 3.1 with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.19.70.

Comment: I'm not sure about Oracle, but the design of most .NET database connections includes the implied intent that the consumer of a connection opens, uses, and disposes the connection on each access.  The connection (and the backing _connection pool_) are responsible for optimizing access, managing concurrency, etc. Try following these guidelines.  I wouldn't deviate too far unless your testing indicated that this was causing you performance issues

Comment: Personally, a connection must be opened for each query to the database and closed after receiving a response.